# Fatal error: Unsupported operand types

Tags: php

I just can't figure it out :(

the complete script...

the trouble lines are noted by "This Line"
I can rem them out and the script will work but only half way :(

```
require_once("global.php");

$kernel->vars['page_struct']['system_page_action_title'] = $kernel->ld['phrase_page_title_statistics'];

// No categories in archive
if ($kernel->db->numrows("SELECT `category_id` FROM `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "categories`") == 0) {
  $kernel->page->message_report($kernel->ld['phrase_no_categories'], M_NOTICE);
}
else {
  $kernel->tp->call("page_statistics");
  $kernel->vars['stats'] = array();

  // Archive Highs
  // This line.
  $kernel->vars['stats'] = $kernel->vars['stats'] + $kernel->db->row("SELECT `file_id` AS `latest_file_id`, `file_name` AS `latest_file_name`, `file_timestamp` AS `latest_file_timestamp` FROM `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "files` ORDER BY `file_id` DESC LIMIT 1");
  $kernel->vars['stats']['latest_file_timestamp'] = $kernel->fetch_time($kernel->vars['stats']['latest_file_timestamp'], DF_SHORT);

  // This line.
  $kernel->vars['stats'] = $kernel->vars['stats'] + $kernel->db->row("SELECT `file_id` AS `mostdl_file_id`, `file_name` AS `mostdl_file_name`, `file_downloads` AS `mostdl_file_downloads` FROM `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "files` ORDER BY `file_downloads` DESC LIMIT 1");
  $kernel->vars['stats']['mostdl_file_downloads'] = $kernel->vars['stats']['mostdl_file_downloads'];

  // This line.
  $kernel->vars['stats'] = $kernel->vars['stats'] + $kernel->db->row("SELECT `file_id` AS `leastdl_file_id`, `file_name` AS `leastdl_file_name`, `file_downloads` AS `leastdl_file_downloads` FROM `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "files` ORDER BY `file_downloads` ASC LIMIT 1");
  $kernel->vars['stats']['leastdl_file_downloads'] = $kernel->vars['stats']['leastdl_file_downloads'];

  // This line.
  $kernel->vars['stats'] = $kernel->vars['stats'] + $kernel->db->row("SELECT `file_id` AS `highrate_file_id`, `file_name` AS `highrate_file_name`, `file_rating` AS `highrate_file_rating`, `file_votes` AS `highrate_file_votes` FROM `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "files` ORDER BY `file_rating` DESC, `file_votes` DESC LIMIT 1");
  $kernel->vars['stats']['highrate_file_rank'] = $kernel->archive->construct_file_rating($kernel->vars['stats']['highrate_file_rating'], $kernel->vars['stats']['highrate_file_votes']);

  // Datastore counters
  $datastore_keys = array("total_announcements", "total_files", "total_categories", "total_users", "total_downloads", "total_votes", "total_images", "total_comments");

  foreach($datastore_keys AS $counter) {
    $kernel->vars['stats']["$counter"] = $kernel->format_input($kernel->db->item("SELECT `datastore_value` FROM `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "datastore` WHERE `datastore_key` = 'count_" . $counter . "'"), T_NUM);
  }

  $kernel->ld['phrase_statistics_message'] = sprintf($kernel->ld['phrase_statistics_message'], $kernel->fetch_time($kernel->config['archive_start'], DF_SHORT), $kernel->archive->format_round_bytes($kernel->db->item("SELECT `datastore_value` FROM `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "datastore` WHERE `datastore_key` = 'count_total_data'")));

  $kernel->tp->cache($kernel->vars['stats']);
}

$kernel->page->construct_output(R_HEADER, R_FOOTER, false, R_NAVIGATION);
```

Comment: Please reformat your question and add what library you use for database handling. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is `$kernel->db->row` an array? I guess it is an object and you can't add object and an array.

Answer (score 2):

We know `$kernel->vars['stats']` is an array, since:

```
$kernel->vars['stats'] = array();
```

Your problem line comes next:

```
$kernel->vars['stats']=$kernel->vars['stats'] + $kernel->db->row( ... );
```

The `+` means a union of 2 arrays, so `$kernel->db->row(...)` must be an array.

Is it?

Comment: You can't add them, but you can merge them this way: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

Comment: @Pekka - yikes. Thanks. Fixed. Then it must be the right hand entity.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be expecting an array as the return value of the `row` method. Not knowing your DB class, we can't say whether that is true, but anyway, you should be checking for the return type first. (Also for the case of errors)

```
$row = $kernel->db->row( "SELECT `file_id` .... " );

if (is_array($row)) 
 $kernel->vars['stats'] = $kernel->vars['stats'] + $row;
```

Comment: mysql, utf8 I am in no way a master :) I am a beginner and learning. this complete program had a lot of errors and this is the last one I can not figure out.